# How to create unique ID for this toggle box in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a re-usable toggle box in React(shown below). It has 2 parts ----left side and the right side. And users can create multiple toggle boxes by clicking the add button.

So I need to create a unique id for the left side and right side and also for the new toggle box added. id={id} doesn't work because both the left side and the right side will have the same id.

Can someone suggest me a way to fix this?

```
functionToggleBar({ nameLeft, nameRight, onChange }) {
    return (
        <div>
            <input
                id="toggle-on"
                className="toggle toggle-left"
                onChange={onChange}
                name="toggle"
                value="false"
                type="radio"
                checked
            />
            <label htmlFor="toggle-on" className="btnn-toggle">
                {nameLeft}
            </label>
            <input
                id="toggle-off"
                className="toggle toggle-right"
                onChange={onChange}
                name="toggle"
                value="true"
                type="radio"
            />
            <label htmlFor="toggle-off" className="btnn-toggle">
                {nameRight}
            </label>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: If you jsut need to distinguish between right and left, then couldn't you just use string interpolation? ```id={`${id}_left`}```, for example.

Comment: You can use `New date().getTime()` which returns an integer as `id` (the number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970). 2 toggle boxes might not be created at the same millisecond so your ids will be unique.